# Spherical coordinate representation (using Ogre maths constructs) fails tests

Tags: c++, 3d, geometry

In my project I need to position things around other things in a spherical way, so I figured I needed a spherical coordinate representation. I'm using [Ogre3D](http://ogre3d.org) graphic rendering engine which provide some maths constructs which at the moment I use everywhere in my project.
The source code of Ogre is available [there, in the 1.9 branch](https://bitbucket.org/sinbad/ogre/src/15926b0d87667f5aa44f73ecde1a63910e500d22/?at=v1-9) as I'm using an old version of it. I checked yesterday that the maths types didn't change in a long time so my code is relying on the code you can see there, in particular [Maths](https://bitbucket.org/sinbad/ogre/src/15926b0d87667f5aa44f73ecde1a63910e500d22/OgreMain/include/OgreMath.h?at=v1-9), [Vector3](https://bitbucket.org/sinbad/ogre/src/15926b0d87667f5aa44f73ecde1a63910e500d22/OgreMain/include/OgreVector3.h?at=v1-9) and [Quaternion](https://bitbucket.org/sinbad/ogre/src/15926b0d87667f5aa44f73ecde1a63910e500d22/OgreMain/include/OgreQuaternion.h?at=v1-9). Here I'm assuming that Ogre's code is correct, but you never know, which is why I'm pointing to it as my code is relying heavily on it. Also know that the referential used in Ogre is right handed, with -Z being the default orientation of any entity, +Y being up of the screen, +X being the right side of the screen, and +Z being the direction toward you, -Z being the direction toward the screen.

Now, here is the spherical coordinate code I have a problem with:

```
#ifndef HGUARD_NETRUSH_ZONEVIEW_SPHERICAL_HPP__
#define HGUARD_NETRUSH_ZONEVIEW_SPHERICAL_HPP__

#include <iosfwd>

#include <OgreMath.h>
#include <OgreVector3.h>
#include <OgreQuaternion.h>

#include "api.hpp"

namespace netrush {
namespace zoneview {

    /** Spherical coordinates vector, used for spherical coordinates and transformations. 
        Some example values:
            ( radius = 1.0, theta = 0.0deg , phi = 0.0deg  ) <=> Y unit vector in cartesian space
            ( radius = 1.0, theta = 90.0deg, phi = 0.0deg  ) <=> Z unit vector in cartesian space
            ( radius = 1.0, theta = 90.0deg , phi = 90.0deg ) <=> X unit vector in cartesian space
    */
    struct SphereVector
    {
        Ogre::Real   radius; ///< Rho or Radius is the distance from the center of the sphere.
        Ogre::Radian theta;  ///< Theta is the angle around the x axis (latitude angle counterclockwise), values range from 0 to PI.
        Ogre::Radian phi;    ///< Phi is the angle around the y axis (longitude angle counterclockwise), values range from 0 to 2PI.

        NETRUSH_ZONEVIEW_API static const SphereVector ZERO;
        NETRUSH_ZONEVIEW_API static const SphereVector UNIT_X;
        NETRUSH_ZONEVIEW_API static const SphereVector UNIT_Y;
        NETRUSH_ZONEVIEW_API static const SphereVector UNIT_Z;
        NETRUSH_ZONEVIEW_API static const SphereVector NEGATIVE_UNIT_X;
        NETRUSH_ZONEVIEW_API static const SphereVector NEGATIVE_UNIT_Y;
        NETRUSH_ZONEVIEW_API static const SphereVector NEGATIVE_UNIT_Z;

        SphereVector() = default;
        SphereVector( Ogre::Real radius, Ogre::Radian theta, Ogre::Radian phi )
            : radius( std::move(radius) ), theta( std::move(theta) ), phi( std::move(phi) )
        {}

        explicit SphereVector( const Ogre::Vector3& cartesian_vec )
        {
            *this = from_cartesian( cartesian_vec );
        }

        void normalize()
        {
            using namespace Ogre;
            while( phi > Degree(360.f) ) phi -= Degree(360.f);
            while( theta > Degree(180.f) ) theta -= Degree(180.f);
            while( phi < Radian(0) ) phi += Degree(360.f);
            while( theta < Radian(0) ) theta += Degree(180.f);

        }

        SphereVector normalized() const 
        {
            SphereVector svec{*this};
            svec.normalize();
            return svec;                
        }


        /** @return a relative Cartesian vector coordinate from this relative spherical coordinate. */
        Ogre::Vector3 to_cartesian() const
        {
            using namespace Ogre;
            const auto svec = normalized();
            Vector3 result;
            result.x = radius * Math::Sin( svec.phi ) * Math::Sin( svec.theta );
            result.z = radius * Math::Cos( svec.phi ) * Math::Sin( svec.theta );
            result.y = radius * Math::Cos( svec.theta );
            return result;
        }

        /** @return a relative spherical coordinate from a cartesian vector. */
        static SphereVector from_cartesian( const Ogre::Vector3& cartesian )
        {
            using namespace Ogre;
            SphereVector result = SphereVector::ZERO;
            result.radius = cartesian.length();
            if( result.radius == 0 )
                return result;
            result.phi    = Math::ATan2( cartesian.x, cartesian.z );
            result.theta  = Math::ATan2( Math::Sqrt( Math::Sqr( cartesian.x ) + Math::Sqr( cartesian.z ) ), cartesian.y );
            result.normalize();
            return result;
        }

        friend SphereVector operator-( const SphereVector& value ) 
        {
            SphereVector result;
            result.radius = -value.radius;
            result.theta  = -value.theta;
            result.phi    = -value.phi;
            return result; 
        }

        friend SphereVector operator+( const SphereVector& left, const SphereVector& right )
        { 
            SphereVector result;
            result.radius = left.radius + right.radius;
            result.theta  = left.theta + right.theta;
            result.phi    = left.phi + right.phi; 
            return result;
        }

        friend SphereVector operator-( const SphereVector& left, const SphereVector& right )
        { 
            return left + (-right); 
        }

        SphereVector& operator+=( const SphereVector& other )
        { 
            *this = *this + other;
            return *this;
        }

        SphereVector& operator-=( const SphereVector& other )
        {
            *this = *this - other;
            return *this;
        }

        /// Rotation of the position around the relative center of the sphere.
        friend SphereVector operator*( const SphereVector& sv, const Ogre::Quaternion& rotation )
        {
            const auto cartesian_vec = sv.to_cartesian();
            const auto rotated_vec = rotation * cartesian_vec;
            SphereVector result { rotated_vec };
            result.normalize();
            return result;
        }

        /// Rotation of the position around the relative center of the sphere.
        friend SphereVector operator*( const Ogre::Quaternion& rotation, const SphereVector& sv ) { return sv * rotation; }

        /// Rotation of the position around the relative center of the sphere.
        SphereVector& operator*=( const Ogre::Quaternion& rotation ) 
        {
            *this = *this * rotation;
            return *this;
        }

        friend bool operator==( const SphereVector& left, const SphereVector& right )
        {
            return Ogre::Math::RealEqual( left.radius, right.radius )
                && left.phi == right.phi
                && left.theta == right.theta
                ;
        }

        friend bool operator!=( const SphereVector& left, const SphereVector& right )
        {
            return !( left == right );
        }

    };


    inline std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& out, const SphereVector& svec )
    {
        out << "{ radius = " << svec.radius
            << ", theta = "  << svec.theta
            << ", phi = "    << svec.phi
            << " }";
        return out;
    }

    inline bool real_equals( const SphereVector& left, const SphereVector& right, Ogre::Real tolerance = 1e-03 )
    {
        using namespace Ogre;
        return Math::RealEqual( left.radius, right.radius, tolerance )
            && Math::RealEqual( left.theta.valueAngleUnits(), right.theta.valueAngleUnits(), tolerance )
            && Math::RealEqual( left.phi.valueAngleUnits(), right.phi.valueAngleUnits(), tolerance )
            ;
    }


}}


#endif
```

The constants are defined in the cpp:

```
 #include "spherical.hpp"


namespace netrush {
namespace zoneview {

    const SphereVector SphereVector::ZERO( 0.f, Ogre::Radian( 0.f ), Ogre::Radian( 0.f ) );
    const SphereVector SphereVector::UNIT_X( Ogre::Vector3::UNIT_X );
    const SphereVector SphereVector::UNIT_Y( Ogre::Vector3::UNIT_Y );
    const SphereVector SphereVector::UNIT_Z( Ogre::Vector3::UNIT_Z );
    const SphereVector SphereVector::NEGATIVE_UNIT_X( Ogre::Vector3::NEGATIVE_UNIT_X );
    const SphereVector SphereVector::NEGATIVE_UNIT_Y( Ogre::Vector3::NEGATIVE_UNIT_Y );
    const SphereVector SphereVector::NEGATIVE_UNIT_Z( Ogre::Vector3::NEGATIVE_UNIT_Z );

}}
```

The failing test (the lines marked ast FAILURE):

```
inline bool check_compare( SphereVector left, SphereVector right )
{
    std::cout << "----"
        << "\nComparing "
        << "\n    Left: " << left
        << "\n    Right: " << right
        << std::endl;

    return real_equals( left, right );
}

// ...

TEST( Test_SphereVector, axe_rotation_quaternion )
{
    using namespace Ogre;
    const auto init_svec = SphereVector::NEGATIVE_UNIT_Z;
    static const auto ROTATION_TO_X             = Vector3::NEGATIVE_UNIT_Z.getRotationTo( Vector3::UNIT_X          );
    static const auto ROTATION_TO_Y             = Vector3::NEGATIVE_UNIT_Z.getRotationTo( Vector3::UNIT_Y          );
    static const auto ROTATION_TO_Z             = Vector3::NEGATIVE_UNIT_Z.getRotationTo( Vector3::UNIT_Z          );
    static const auto ROTATION_TO_NEGATIVE_X    = Vector3::NEGATIVE_UNIT_Z.getRotationTo( Vector3::NEGATIVE_UNIT_X );
    static const auto ROTATION_TO_NEGATIVE_Y    = Vector3::NEGATIVE_UNIT_Z.getRotationTo( Vector3::NEGATIVE_UNIT_Y );
    static const auto ROTATION_TO_NEGATIVE_Z    = Vector3::NEGATIVE_UNIT_Z.getRotationTo( Vector3::NEGATIVE_UNIT_Z );
    static const auto ROTATION_360              = ROTATION_TO_Z * 2;

    const auto svec_x    = init_svec * ROTATION_TO_X;
    const auto svec_y    = init_svec * ROTATION_TO_Y;
    const auto svec_z    = init_svec * ROTATION_TO_Z;
    const auto svec_nx   = init_svec * ROTATION_TO_NEGATIVE_X;
    const auto svec_ny   = init_svec * ROTATION_TO_NEGATIVE_Y;
    const auto svec_nz   = init_svec * ROTATION_TO_NEGATIVE_Z;
    const auto svec_360  = init_svec * ROTATION_360;

    EXPECT_TRUE( check_compare( svec_x.to_cartesian()  , Vector3::UNIT_X          ) );
    EXPECT_TRUE( check_compare( svec_y.to_cartesian()  , Vector3::UNIT_Y          ) );
    EXPECT_TRUE( check_compare( svec_z.to_cartesian()  , Vector3::UNIT_Z          ) );
    EXPECT_TRUE( check_compare( svec_nx.to_cartesian() , Vector3::NEGATIVE_UNIT_X ) );
    EXPECT_TRUE( check_compare( svec_ny.to_cartesian() , Vector3::NEGATIVE_UNIT_Y ) );
    EXPECT_TRUE( check_compare( svec_nz.to_cartesian() , Vector3::NEGATIVE_UNIT_Z ) );
    EXPECT_TRUE( check_compare( svec_360.to_cartesian(), Vector3::NEGATIVE_UNIT_Z ) ); // FAILURE 1

    EXPECT_TRUE( check_compare( svec_x  , SphereVector::UNIT_X          ) );
    EXPECT_TRUE( check_compare( svec_y  , SphereVector::UNIT_Y          ) ); // FAILURE 2
    EXPECT_TRUE( check_compare( svec_z  , SphereVector::UNIT_Z          ) );
    EXPECT_TRUE( check_compare( svec_nx , SphereVector::NEGATIVE_UNIT_X ) );
    EXPECT_TRUE( check_compare( svec_ny , SphereVector::NEGATIVE_UNIT_Y ) ); // FAILURE 3
    EXPECT_TRUE( check_compare( svec_nz , SphereVector::NEGATIVE_UNIT_Z ) );
    EXPECT_TRUE( check_compare( svec_360, SphereVector::NEGATIVE_UNIT_Z ) ); // FAILURE 4

}
```

Excerpt from the test report:
Failure 1:

```
4>  ----
4>  Comparing 
4>      Left: Vector3(9.61651e-007, -3.0598e-007, 7)
4>      Right: Vector3(0, 0, -1)
4>e:\projects\games\netrush\netrush_projects\projects\netrush\zoneview\tests\spherevector.cpp(210): error : Value of: check_compare( svec_360.to_cartesian(), Vector3::NEGATIVE_UNIT_Z )
4>    Actual: false
4>  Expected: true
```

Failure 2:

```
4>  ----
4>  Comparing 
4>      Left: { radius = 1, theta = Radian(1.4783e-007), phi = Radian(5.65042) }
4>      Right: { radius = 1, theta = Radian(0), phi = Radian(0) }
4>e:\projects\games\netrush\netrush_projects\projects\netrush\zoneview\tests\spherevector.cpp(213): error : Value of: check_compare( svec_y , SphereVector::UNIT_Y )
4>    Actual: false
4>  Expected: true
```

Failure 3:

```
4>  ----
4>  Comparing 
4>      Left: { radius = 1, theta = Radian(3.14159), phi = Radian(5.82845) }
4>      Right: { radius = 1, theta = Radian(3.14159), phi = Radian(0) }
4>e:\projects\games\netrush\netrush_projects\projects\netrush\zoneview\tests\spherevector.cpp(216): error : Value of: check_compare( svec_ny , SphereVector::NEGATIVE_UNIT_Y )
4>    Actual: false
4>  Expected: true
```

Failure 4:

```
4>  Comparing 
4>      Left: { radius = 7, theta = Radian(1.5708), phi = Radian(1.37379e-007) }
4>      Right: { radius = 1, theta = Radian(1.5708), phi = Radian(3.14159) }
4>e:\projects\games\netrush\netrush_projects\projects\netrush\zoneview\tests\spherevector.cpp(218): error : Value of: check_compare( svec_360, SphereVector::NEGATIVE_UNIT_Z )
4>    Actual: false
4>  Expected: true
```

- The same code on gist: https://gist.github.com/Klaim/8633895 with constants defined there: https://gist.github.com/Klaim/8634224
- Full tests (using GTest): https://gist.github.com/Klaim/8633917
- Full test report: https://gist.github.com/Klaim/8633937
  (I can't put it here because of the text size limitation)

As you can see in the error report, there is 4 errors. I just can't find a solution for these, so maybe someone here could point me to what I'm doing wrong. I believe the problem could be from the test itself, but I'm not sure at all. Also, note that there are tests missing that I plan to add. The

The api.hpp include only expose the macros for shared library symbol export/import, used for constants.

This code is supposed to be extracted to be provided as a separate small open source library.

What I'm asking is: is this code incorrect? Or is my test incorrect?

Comment: 1) That is a **lot** of code, and many tests (the code passes most and fails four). You should whittle this down to a [minimal complete example](http://sscce.org) of **one** failure (and maybe a couple of "nearby" cases that pass). 2) At the very least it would be nice if you indicated which of the tests fail-- it's not obvious. 3) You say that the coordinate system is left-handed, but the definition you give (+Y upward on the screen, +X to the right on the screen, +Z out of the screen toward the viewer) is right-handed.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, will fix all this. I wanted to provide a max of info. It's right handed indeed.

Comment: However, so far I couldn't reduce the minimal complete example as separately the functions are tested and are apparently correct (see the full report and tests), but maybe the tests are flawed. If the error is mathematics I fear that I'm not understanding the mistake. Which is why I'm posting.